# Is there a way to get Chrome to use a %20 instead of a + sign for spaces when using keyword search?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to use Chrome's keyword search omnibox functionality to search a website which is not available to the public. When you type a search term with spaces in it in the website, the URL that gets produced looks like this:

```
https://example.com/default.aspx?view=slg/search#txt=My%20search%20%with%20spaces
```

Unfortunately when I type a search using the keyword in Chrome's omnibox, I get this:

```
https://example.com/default.aspx?view=slg/search#txt=My+search+with+spaces
```

[Previous questions of Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/281934/forcing-s-to-escape-spaces-with-plus-instead-of-percent-twenty) have had the opposite occur. That is the omnibox has converted their spaces to a `%20` instead of a `+`.  [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/282444/204358) indicates that chrome guesses which to use.  Does anyone know of a way to hint to Chrome that it should use a `%20` instead of a `+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a way to do this, so I ended up writing an [open source extension](https://github.com/MarkIannucci/ChromeUserWebSearchExtension) for Chrome.  I'll warn you, it is hard coded to the `https://privatewebsite.com/`, so you won't be able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> it for your needs, but it is available under the MIT license for you to use as necessary.

I think the most important aspect of what I did was to use the `encodeURIComponent(searchText)` javascript function to get the `%20`'s I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, so I made a simple transit page (redirect_chrome_search.html) with the following JS to redirect to the target page:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let url = params.get('url');
params.delete('url');
location = url + '?' + params.toString().replaceAll('+', '%20');
```

For Chrome's Query URL I use:

```
redirect_chrome_search.html?url=https://example.com/default.aspx&text=%s
```